# Hi! How do I return html tags with HTTPClass?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, httprequest

I have the example that returns html taken from file:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                await next();

                if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
                {
                    // context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                    context.Request... = "<div>Test</div>";
                    await next();
                }
            });
        }
```

I need to return HTML by string directly somehow like:

```
context.Request... = "<div>Test</div>";
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Write to the *response*, not the request

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Danke! You can post an answer.